# Can't Insert data into database using NHibernate

Tags: c#, postgresql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm new in NHibernate I write code which is simple should insert into database information about users that's it 
the code  is below

**UserClassModel**

```
 class Users
    {
        public virtual int id { get; set; }
        public virtual string username { get; set; }
        public virtual string password { get; set; }
        public virtual string role { get; set; }
        public virtual bool deleted { get; set; }
        public virtual DateTime create_date { get; set; }

    }
```

**UserMapClass**

```
 class UserMap : ClassMap<Users>
{
    public UserMap() 
    {
        Id(x => x.id);
        Map(x => x.username);
        Map(x => x.password);
        Map(x => x.deleted);
        Map(x => x.role);
        Map(x => x.create_date);


    }

}
```

**Connection where I try to insert data into database using NHibernate**

```
class Connection
    {
        public Connection() 
        {
            var sefact = createFactory();
            using (var session = sefact.OpenSession())
            {
                using (var txt = session.BeginTransaction()) 
                {
                    var users = new Users
                    {

                        username = "jakhongir",
                        password = "2356+"


                    };
                    session.Save(users);
                }
            }




        }
        private static ISessionFactory createFactory()
        {

            string connectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1; Port=5433; User Id=smartwarehouse; Password=$smart#2018;Database=warehouse;";
            IPersistenceConfigurer config = PostgreSQLConfiguration.PostgreSQL82.ConnectionString(connectionString);
            FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently.Configure().Database(config).Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.Add(typeof(UserMap)));



            return configuration.BuildSessionFactory();



        }
```

here is code I can't insert it into database it gives following errors 
[image]

here is database part of 
[image]

Comment: Just a small remark, avoid posting screenshots unless absolutely necessary... The exception (with it's stack trace) and the CREATE TABLE statement can be just as well pasted as text.

Answer (score 0):

Rename your Model class to 'User' from 'Users' (Generally it's a good practice to use singular names for the model, as it represents a single entity)

```
class User
{
    public virtual int id { get; set; }
    public virtual string username { get; set; }
    public virtual string password { get; set; }
    public virtual string role { get; set; }
    public virtual bool deleted { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime create_date { get; set; }

}
```

The mapping class must derive from ClassMap :

```
// Creating the map class
public UserMap:ClassMap<User>
{
    // The constructor of Mapping class
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.id);
        Map(x => x.username);
        Map(x => x.password);
        Map(x => x.deleted);
        Map(x => x.role);
        Map(x => x.create_date); 
    }  
}
```

Comment: it is matter to change Users into user

Comment: I've added the reason in the brackets. A lot of ORM map the model objects to a table name equivalent to the plural form of their name, in case if the table name is not specified. For e.g, in EntityFramework if you don't specify a table name for 'User' model, then it will automatically create a table named 'Users' and map User model to the table. Therefore to avoid the confusion, you should have model names in the singular form.

Comment: Although, to your question the issue doesn't seems to be with the name and It was that the map class wasn't derived from ClassMap. If you don't want to touch the Model name for now, you can leave it. But, that remains a recommendation.

Comment: thank you for your recomendation but its still give the same errors again and again

Comment: Even with the new Map class ?

Comment: unfortunetaly yes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178019/discussion-between-praveen-rai-and-mansur-otabekov).